# When i mount the file system in windows server then Network Error 85 occured

Tags: amazon-web-services, mount, amazon-fsx

I have configured AWS OpenZFS with Windows Server 2016. I have installed NFS client on Windows Server. I got the Network Error 85 when I tried to mount the file system with D: drive. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check these pages

- [System error 85 with the NET USE command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/system-error-85-net-use-command)  for windows 10
- [How to Fix System Error 85](https://www.compuchenna.co.uk/system-error-85/)

Please notice that use this solutions as your own risks.

(change windows registry is dangerous action, may cause system crash, data loss and worse)

Comment: I will take a look and work with windows registry editor.